# RedBean: A database has already been specified for this key

Tags: php, redbean

i'm having some problems with RedBean. I'm getting an connection error and can't figure out what is the meaning, i have already looked on Google and couldn't find any valid solution, i tried a similar question here but the answer didn't really help on this case.

I have two classes, User and DAL.

DAL Class:

```
namespace Models;

use Config\Helpers as Helpers;
use Lib\RedBean\R as R;
use Lib\RedBean\Plugin\ModelValidation as ModelValidation;

class DAL extends R
{
    function __construct()
    {
        R::setup( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=angularjs', 'user', 'pass' );

        R::ext('validate', function($bean)
        {
            return ModelValidation::validate($bean);
        });
    }

    public function createBean($tableName)

    public function create($bean)

    public function read($tableName, $id = 0)

    function __destruct()
    {
       R::close();
    }
}
```

User Class:

```
namespace Models;

use Models\DAL as DAL;
use Lib\JWT\JWT as JWT;
use Config\Helpers as Helpers;
use Lib\RedBean\SimpleModel as SimpleModel;

class Usuario extends SimpleModel
{
    public static $rules = [
        'login' => [
            'label' => 'Login',
            'filter' => 'trim|sanitize_string',
            'validation' => 'required|alpha_numeric',
        ],
        'senha' => [
            'label' => 'Senha',
            'validation' => 'required|alpha_numeric|min_len,6',
            'message' => 'I don not like this password. This is an example of a bad message.'
        ],
    ];

    public function login()

    public function logout()

    public function criaUsuario()
    {
        $DAL = new DAL();

        //user creation code
    }

    public function criaToken($usuarioId = 0)
    {
        $DAL = new DAL();

        //Token creation code
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Lib\RedBean\RedException' with message 'A database has already been specified for this key.' in D:\Projetos\Market Media\backend\Lib\RedBean\Facade.php:288
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Projetos\Market Media\backend\Lib\RedBean\Facade.php(206): Lib\RedBean\Facade::addDatabase('default', 'mysql:host=loca...', 'angularjs', 'root', false)
#1 D:\Projetos\Market Media\backend\Models\DAL.php(13): Lib\RedBean\Facade::setup('mysql:host=loca...', 'angularjs', 'root')
#2 D:\Projetos\Market Media\backend\Models\Usuario.php(67): Models\DAL->__construct()
#3 D:\Projetos\Market Media\backend\Models\Usuario.php(56): Models\Usuario->criaToken('27')
#4 D:\Projetos\Market Media\backend\API\UsuarioAPI.php(42): Models\Usuario->criaUsuario()
#5 D:\Projetos\Market Media\backend\API\BaseAPI.php(82): API\UsuarioAPI->criaUsuario(Array)
#6 D:\Projetos\Market Media\backend\Controllers\UsuarioController.php(13): API\BaseAPI->processAPI()
#7 D:\Projetos\Market Media\backend\index.php(26): Controllers\UsuarioController->start()
# in D:\Projetos\Market Media\backend\Lib\RedBean\Facade.php on line 288
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

every time you create a new instance of DAL rb try ro setup a database on "default" key, try to place R::setup out of class, once in application

Comment: Silly me, the constructor wasn't the smartest place to put the connection ! Thanks

Comment: anti-pattern alert!

Answer (score 9):

if you use **R::setup()** function inside construct method you most use this syntax:

```
public __construct (){
    if(!R::testConnection()){
        R::setup($DSN, $USER, $PASSWORD);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for this error is that your connection details may be incorrect. Such as database name, username or password. First of all check your connection details and then try other solutions.